# Pokémon Go without Google at all

Tags: google-account, google-play-games, pokemon-go

I bought an android phone recently and tried to use it without any Google account and so far that was alright. 
But I wanted to try Pokémon Go today and I cannot play without signing up with a Google account. 
I heard that you could create a Pokémon club account instead of Google but I don't even have the option, only the button to sign up with google appears.

Does anybody have a solution for that?

Comment: You could ask this on our sister site for gaming Q&A (http://arqade.stackexchange.com). Possibly. Refer their on-topic guidelines to see if this question would be acceptable there. It probably would be, and since they have a community of users around Pokemon Go, you would probably find more help there than here.

Comment: Maybe [Lucky Patcher](https://lucky-patcher.netbew.com)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Creating a Google Account is currently your only option, It's not hard to create a new account and it will probably be beneficial for many other applications you might download.  It's annoying to create a whole new account just to keep things separated but it's necessary to gain access to Google's location features on Android.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Pokémon GO relies on Google positioning and map frameworks, so theoretically you are *required* to have Google Apps, or at least (?) Google Play, Google Maps and Google Play Services. Without them, even if you managed to log in without Google, you will not be able to get GPS position.

Answer (score 0):

*Revoke Pokémon GO’s Access to Your Google Account*

You must login to the Google account permissions page and look for the entry “Pokemon Go Release”. Click on it for a detailed view and then, click the giant “REMOVE” button.
But i have to tell you that this may lead to your Pokemon Game STOP.

Use a Burner Google Account

Okay, we get it. You want to keep playing, but are (rightfully) dubious about handing over your account. Here’s a little workaround: **create another free Google account, with nothing in it,** and use that to sign into Pokémon GO.

I think sooner or later, Pokemon Go won't require Google Play Acc anymore. This is a ridiculous thing about this game. I heard that Pokemon Go on Itunes no longer requires this account.

Comment: Revoking access isn't applicable to the question, because the questioner doesn't have a Google account to start with.

Answer (score -3):

Its only in certain countrys as part of a limit release for the beta but thankfully apkmirror uploaded it , they're a very safe site enjoy.

http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/niantic-inc/pokemon-go/pokemon-go-0-29-0-release/pokemon-go-0-29-0-android-apk-download/

Comment: The problem is not about downloading and installing it, but the problem seems to be requiring to sign in to Google account just before you can play it (after installing it, of course).

Comment: then youd create a pokemon account

Answer (score -3):

If you do not see the "login with google" option you probably specified a too young age on the start screen when asked about you birthdate.
At least this was the problem when I had it, too.

You would only have to enter your birthdate once at the very first start of the app, but you have to enter it again if you clear the cache, apparently.

Comment: The questioner **does** see the "login with google" option. They want to use another login option.